# Configure Windows Azure webjobs sdk for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have an existing application developed in Visual Studio 2012 with .Net framework 4. And my project is hosted on cloud Azure. 
I want to add a Windows Azure WebJob project in it but cannot find extension to configure this.

I find an extension given below but it is not working for 2012
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4824551-2660-4afa-aba1-1fcc1673c3d0

Is there any way to configure it for 2012. I have Windows Azure 2.2 sdk installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the tooling is only available for VS 2013.

However, if you want to use the WebJobs SDK, you can get the NuGet package and create the WebJob but you will have to deploy it manually.